# How get new size of a Stretched TImage in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

In delphi XE7 I have a control Image With property Image.Strech := True

When load image from disk, it resize automatically inside TImage control. How can get the size of resized image, or alternatively how can get a copy of showed bitmap (not orginal of TPicture part of Timage )

Thanks

Comment: The stretched size is the same size as the TImage, so it would be in TImage.Height and TImage.Width. There is no *copy of showed bitmap*; it's a stretched drawing of the original bitmap. If you want a copy, then create a new bitmap and draw the stretched image from the original using TBitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw or the WinAPI function StretchDIBits.

Comment: @KenWhite is right. But if `TImage.Proportional` is true, you also need to compensate for the aspect ratio (simple case of an `if` statement plus a multiplication, basically).